# Generating output objects?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

I'm currently writing a few commands as PowerShell `cmdlets` and had no issue doing what I need to so far (process objects from the pipeline). However I now need to do something different, start from nothing and generate objects (that is , I have no records as input, just a simple text `param`, and I need to generate data for the next stage of the pipeline).

How would I "pass" new data to the pipeline? Could someone provide me a sample for a command like out-generate -size X that would generate X sequential ints in the pipeline in such a way that I could do

```
out-generate -size 10 | out-gridview
```

So far I have no idea how to send data as output, I know how to write data (`WriteObject`) but I'm assuming (perhaps wrongly) it only writes the textual representation and doesn't send the object to the pipeline. Or do I simply need to pass things to `WriteObject`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Write-Output` cmdlet. However, it's the default cmdlet, which will be executed if the return value of a statement (either by just using the variable name or the return value of a cmdlet) is the 'end of the statement'.

So you could either do the following, by explicitly calling Write-Output (I find this make the code easier to read):

```
function Get-Integers
{
    PARAM (
        $NumberOfIntegers
    )

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $NumberOfIntegers; $i ++)
    {
        Write-Output $i
    }
}

Get-Integers 10 | Out-GridView
```

Or you could just ignore the `Write-Output` call.

```
function Get-Integers
{
    PARAM (
        $NumberOfIntegers
    )

    for($i = 0; $i -lt $NumberOfIntegers; $i ++)
    {
        $i
    }
}

Get-Integers 10 | Out-GridView
```

The documentation on `Write-Output` (which you can get if you call `Get-Help Write-Output -Full`) states, among other things:

> Sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline. If the command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are displayed in the console.

Comment: That's not my question, you're showing how to write to the pipeline from a function, i'm trying to do so from a cmdlet (as in writing an actual dll based command in C#)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that in your question. However, you should just use the [equivalent cmdlet command `Cmdlet.WriteObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms568371(v=vs.85).aspx). The behaviour still stands, that it send the object to the pipeline and if it's last in the pipeline it'll print to the console.

Comment: @robert.westerlund pedantically it would be more accurate to say that if it is the last in the pipeline it will pipe into the Out-Default cmdlet. It's the Out-Default cmdlet that formats and writes the output to the host.

Comment: Very true. I got hooked on the qoute from the `Get-Help Write_Output -Full` included above. But you are right about `Out-Default`. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

In the end it seems that calling WriteObject actually does exactly that unless what i first thought (it doesn't write the object to the console as text, but actually writes it as an object to the pipeline as i needed).